# Canvas is not Showing Image/Drawable

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, svg-android

I am doing a work on SVG Paths and Image. I have loaded SVG file and get an image and try to set thi image on canvas . But canvas is not showing image. I check the height and width and null check of this image/picture and it is not null so i am unable to understand that why canvas is not showing image. any help

**My code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    Context c;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




        c=getApplicationContext();
        setContentView(new GameView(this));
    }


    public class GameView extends View{
        private int width, height;

        private long svgId;

        Picture picture;

        long startTime;
        float scaleFactor;

        public GameView(Context context) {
            super(context);



            SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(),R.raw.android);
            picture = svg.getPicture();




        }



        @Override

        protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {

            // get visible area

            width = right - left;

            height = bottom - top;

        }



        @Override

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            // paint a white background...

            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

            if (canvas!=null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(c, "yahooooooooooooooooo"+picture.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                scaleFactor=Math.min((float)getHeight()/picture.getHeight(),(float)getWidth()/picture.getWidth());
                canvas.scale((float)scaleFactor,(float)scaleFactor);
                canvas.drawPicture(picture);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just to test your implementation, change your `canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);` to say `canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);`. If this works then something is wrong with your SVG. Also your comment says you paint it white.

Comment: @SimonZettervall i tried from black to red and it is showing red. But thing is i also check that is my svg is null but it is giving "not null" and i also mentioned that i can access the height and width of picture. regarding paint i did not include it

Comment: Just to check, have you opened the SVG in for instance Photoshop and can confirm it is not transparent or something?

Comment: yes i have opened it in browser and its showing an image..

Comment: And your image is called "android"?

Comment: open this link this is my R.raw.android https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/downloads/detail?name=android.svg

Comment: Please call `invalidate()` on your GameView in for instance `onResume()`. It might be that it has not been allocated or something yet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42584/discussion-between-user42590-and-simon-zettervall)

Comment: can you please continue this discussion in chat?

Comment: can you please guide me how can i call invalidate()??

Comment: i called it like that canvas.drawPicture(picture);
    invalidate(); butt nothing

Comment: What device/ OS are you using to test this?

Comment: I am testing my code on Note 10.1 Spen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use to return a drawable object that I will use through all my app
It works quite well.

```
final BitmapDrawable getSVG_Drawable
    (int svgResourceID, int width, int height)
{
    // Get a Picture from the SVG in res/raw.
    final SVG vector =
        SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), svgResourceID);

    final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    // Redraw the picture to a new size.
    final Bitmap bmp =
        Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas cnv = new Canvas(bmp);
    cnv.setDensity((int) (metrics.xdpi));

    cnv.drawPicture(vector.getPicture(), new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
    final BitmapDrawable drw = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);

    // Return the drawable.
    return drw;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I'm using it succesfully, so I thought it would work for you as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is a known issue with svg-android that with certain images, the hardware acceleration can actually cause the image to not show up. I'm not sure of the exact circumstances of what causes this, but I do know it happened to me, as I documented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20365522/544198). The key is to disable hardware acceleration for the view. Depending on what your target it, you might not need to do something quite as fancy as I did (Android 3.0+ doesn't need to check the build version), but here's the key part. Add the code I included in the constructor to your constructor, then add the `disableHardwareAcceleration` bit

```
public GameView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    {
        disableHardwareAcceleration();
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void disableHardwareAcceleration()
{
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```